# Sufficient statistic: prove Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem using conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

I am studying the following problem:

> Consider $X = (X^{(1)}, \ldots, X^{(n)})$ a random variable drawn from a distribution with density $p_{\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \Theta$, where $\theta$ is itself a random variable. Assume that the joint distribution of $(X, \theta)$ has the density $p(x, \theta) = p(x\mid\theta)p(\theta)$. The statistic $T(X)$ is said to be a sufficient statistic if there exists functions $f$ and $h$ such that for any $x$
>
> $$ 
> p(x\mid\theta) = h(x, T(x))f(T(x), \theta)
> $$
>
> Show that $T$ is a sufficient statistic if and only if $\theta$ and $X$ are conditionally independent given $T$.

I have found a few proofs online, and they usually suppose that either all variables are discrete or all of them are continuous. I was thinking about proving a similar result in a more general case, in order to take into account all the possibilities (for example, $X$ and $T(X)$ continuous and $\theta$ discrete, or $X$ and $\theta$ continuous and $T(X)$ discrete). For that, I reformulated the problem using conditional expectations:

> Prove that there exists measurable functions $g$ and $h$ such that, for all measurable $f$:
>   $$
> E[f(X)\mid\theta] = h(X, T(X))g(T(X), \theta)
> $$
>
> if and only if
>
> $$
> E[\phi(X)\psi(\theta)\mid T(X)] = E[\phi(X)\mid T(X)] E[\psi(\theta)\mid T(X)]
> $$
>
> for all measurable $\psi$, $\phi$.

I would like to know if it is true (and how to prove it, if it is), as I couldn't prove it myself. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your generalization of the sufficient statistic definition. The rhs does not depend on $f$, which is weird. IMO a good generalization would $E[f(\theta)|X]=E[f(\theta)|T(X)]$ for every measurable $f$.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for in madprob's answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161048/a-question-about-a-proof-of-neymans-factorization-theorem