# Proof of $P_{\theta}(X=x,T=t) = P_{\theta}(X=x)$ in Neyman's factorization theorem

Tags: statistics

As seeing the comment on the 2nd answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161048/a-question-about-a-proof-of-neymans-factorization-theorem), mentioning delta function, I tried to write the proof of that part.

***Proof***

As $T(\mathbf{x})=t\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{x}) \Rightarrow \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}$ is necessary to $\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x})=t$.

Therefore, $\{\{\omega \mid\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}\} \cap \{\omega \mid\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x})=t\}\}=\{\omega \mid\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}\}$.

$\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{x})$ is an indicator function, which is defined

$$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {1} _{X}(x):={\begin{cases}1~&{\text{ if }}~x\in X~,\\0~&{\text{ if }}~x\notin X~.\end{cases}}}
$$

***Question***

Is this correct? Note that I am not used to writing a rigorous proof in English so some notations might be awkward.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? $P_{\theta}(X=x,T=t)=P_{\theta}(X=x)$ is not true in general unless $\{X=x\}\subset \{T=t\}$, in which case this is just a general fact: $$P(A\cap B) = P(A),\quad A\subset B$$, as $A\cap B = A$

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewZhang. I really appreciate your comment. Let me ask you a question. Is it always true that $P_{\theta}(X=x,T=t)=P_{\theta}(X=x)$ if there is an assumption of $T(x) = t$, because $T$ is derives from $X$ and we can say that $\{X=x\}\subset \{T=t\}$? That is the only thing that my textbook says about the assumption of this theorem.

Comment: It may make things clearer if you write $T=f(X)$, for some $f$. Then, provided $x\in \{u:f(u)=t\}$, one has $\{ X=x\}\subset \{T=t\}$.

Comment: Yes, that is clearer and more obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the comment of the question. Thanks to Andrew, I understand what I was wrong and where to start.

***Summary***

Given $T(\mathbf{x})=t$, $T$ can be written as $T=f(X)$, for some $f$.

Then for $x\in \{u:f(u)=t\}$, one has $\{ X=x\}\subset \{T=t\}$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).